# How to add to a javascript var array using content_for in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, content-for

Right now in my code I'm calling content_for like...

`<% content_for :javascript do -%>
    <%= "var boxplot_data=#{@survey.boxplot_answers.to_json};" %>
  <% end -%>`

Rather then having to convert a whole array at once I'd rather add to the array boxplot_data and then have it display as a var.  That way I can make my code easier to read because right now where I use that data in my partial isn't near where I generate it to add to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best approach would be to define a helper:

```
def add_to_boxplot(val)
  @boxplot ||= []
  @boxplot << val
end

def json_boxplot
  "var boxplot_data = #{@boxplot.to_json}"
end
```

Then in your view just use `add_to_boxplot` and in your layout instead of `yield(:javascript)` use `json_boxplot`.